# Keeping Time constant instead of speed of light in "Special Theory of Relativity"

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

I was reading special theory of relativity and I figured out that, basically this whole theory is revolving around three main factors.

1. Motion(speed)
2. Time
3. Space (length)

The result of Michelson–Morley experiment was, that there is no change in speed of light in any direction, relative to "hypothetical ether".
So Einstein concluded that, speed of light always remains constant, and what changes is "time(dilation)" and "length(contraction)" in order to keep speed of light constant.

But What will happen, if I assume that, the speed of light, and length changes to keep "time as a constant" (one factor out of three must remain constant). Will it satisfy all the laws of physics?

Comment: Then your universe contradicts the experimental results found by Michelson and Morley. Simple as that.

Comment: The much maligned but (IMO) very useful Wikipedia has a good page on the [History of Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity) which might help you.  Special Relativity (and especially the Lorentz Transformation) were the result of a *long, long* process of development by many people.  As @JohnDvorak points out the end target is a theory that matches experiment, and SR is what does.

Comment: Isn't that going to give you Newtonian physics ?  You're talking about absolute time.  I don't think you can get length contraction without time dilation, but I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: I was just taking one out of those three factors a constant, if I take length a constant, then time and speed must vary @StephenG But yes without length contraction in absolute time, it will revert back to Newtonian mechanics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that such a change would yield a theory that would "Obey all the laws of physics" because the fact that lightspeed is constant *is* a law of physics, verified by many experiments in the past century, including the most famous negative result of all time, the Michelsen-Morley interferometric investigation.

Time-dilation and length contraction are consequences of the constancy of the speed of light. The fact that both of these phenomena are experimentally verified is evidence that c is constant and finite. If you make time constant and allow c to vary, you are no longer changing frames of reference using Lorentz transforms, and you are not predicting the physics of our universe.